# CloudConvert via Laravel wrapper: converted file not saved on local disk

Tags: php, laravel, cloud, cloudconvert

I'm trying out a **[Laravel wrapper](https://github.com/robbiepaul/cloudconvert-laravel)** for CloudConvert, so I'm using one of the examples from GitHub to check the basic file conversion. My code is the following:

```
$path = storage_path('app');
CloudConvert::file($path.'/test.jpg')->to($path.'/test.pdf');
```

so basically I want to convert **test.jpg** file to **test.pdf**. Both source and output files should be taken from/saved under `storage/app`.

Thing is, the conversion takes place but the output file is not being saved under the specified path (nor anywhere in the project). I know the conversion is successful, because I can see it in my CloudConvert account, and I can download the PDF after conversion from CloudConvert directly.

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the output file stored?

I also tried to change the destination path to use `public` directory - no luck.

Comment: Hello @lessugar,

It's strange that the file isn't getting saved to disk. You mentioned you're using Homestead in your email so your permissions should be fine. What version of Homestead / Laravel are you using? I'll try to reproduce

Comment: @RobbieP Homestead 0.2.7, Laravel 5.2. I also tried to convert and save on my public server - same thing: converted file is there to download only on CloudConvert direclty. I also tried the non-blocking way with no success (https://github.com/robbiepaul/cloudconvert-laravel#non-blocking-conversion-using-a-callback-url).

Comment: Yea, it seems it was a bug introduced in the last release. The 'wait' option was being set to `false` on local files which was causing the process to exit before the file could be saved. I've released a patch, so just do a `composer update robbiep/cloudconvert-laravel` and it should fix it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Just checked it and it works. Thanks a lot!